# Alternatives for MDWAMP in Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wamp-protocol

Can anyone suggest me good alternative library for [MDWamp](https://github.com/mogui/MDWamp) I have been using this library from a long time by looks like it no longer updated.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: [pusher-websocket-swift](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift)

Comment: check this [Startscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream)